# Tag synonyms for Qt4/Qt and PyQt4/PyQt tags

Tags: support, synonym-request

Consider adding these synonyms:

- [qt4](/questions/tagged/qt4) synonym to [qt](/questions/tagged/qt)
- [pyqt4](/questions/tagged/pyqt4) synonym to [pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt)

IMO, the overwhelming majority of those who seeks `qt`/`pyqt` questions is actually using/interested in `qt4`/`pyqt4`.

If you agree, please add these synonyms, as I don't have this right.

Comment: "the overwhelming majority of those who seeks qt/pyqt questions is actually using/interested in qt4/pyqt4" **today**. There are still qt3 users out there, and there might be (who knows) qt5 users down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea if the majority of those looking for [qt](/questions/tagged/qt)/[pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt) questions are actually looking for [qt4](/questions/tagged/qt4)/[pyqt4](/questions/tagged/pyqt4) but they are not synonyms.

[qt4](/questions/tagged/qt4)/[pyqt4](/questions/tagged/pyqt4) are version specific tags, and they should be used on questions that are specific to the version.

What happens when qt5 comes out? The version 4 tags will probably get outdated soon as qt5 grows in popularity, and most qt/pyqt questions will probably refer to version 5.

And so on, for every version, and every version specific tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4 . They refer both to the same version of qt, but people (including myself) use different tags.

Comment: @warwaruk First, click edit on my answer to see the markup I'm using to generate the tag links (they are actually the same links you have in your comment). Now, although people may expect qt to refer to qt4, that will change when qt5 is out (soon, as the current version is 4.8)... It doesn't make sense to make them synonyms, and generally that's true for every version specific tag on StackOverflow. Version specific tags are not synonyms of their "parent" tags. If people are not using tags correctly, that's another problem, not solved by synonyms.

Comment: 1. When i add a comment, not an answer, i don't have the toolbar to insert a link, and i don't [want] remember how to do this 2. I agree with your reason, but i think the problem i raised also exists. I think there are two answers to the issue: a) Accept there is no solution in current circumstances; b) Introduce hierarchical tags like qt - > [qt3, qt4, qt5]

Comment: @warwaruk Oh, just write `[tag:qt]` and the link to the tag is inserted automatically... No toolbar in comments needed :) As for the hierarchical tags, what most of as do is add both tags (`[qt]` & `[qt4]`) to version specific questions, you can do that as well. Or you could post a meta question for a feature request, so the developers can answer that...